# Python __setitem__ default

Tags: python

I am trying to make a pretty simple class involving a dict. This works fine below for what I want to do. However I am not really making any changes to the `__setitem__` function. I think I could just take it out, but I am not sure how to correct my code to do this. The only real change I am making is to the `__getiten__` function. So I would want `__setitem__` to work just like:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):

        return self._d.__setitem__(key, value)
```

Is there not a way I can do this with out calling `__setitem__` since what I am having it do is its normal behavior?

```
class MyDict:

    def __init__(self, default_value):

        self.default_value = default_value
        self._d = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):

        try:
            self._d.__getitem__(key)
            return self._d.__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            return(self.default_value)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):

        return self._d.__setitem__(key, value)
```

Comment: What you suggest is correct, unless you want to subclass `dict` then just not implement `__getitem__`. But why not just use a vanilla dictionary `d.get(key, default_value)`?

Comment: You are making changes to the `__setitem__` method... you are having it place the data in `self._d'. Without `__setitem__`, attempts to do something like `item['foo'] = 'bar'` would fail with an `AttributeError`.